# Analytic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $0$, and Let $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic map. Suppose $f$ is locally constant at 0, i.e. there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that $f|_U$ is constant. Does it follow that $f$ is constant on $G$?

I know this would hold for continuous maps if $f$ would be locally constant for all $z\in G$, but does being analytic imply that it is enough if it only holds for $z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Call that constant as $k$ and consider $g(z)=f(z)-k$. Any neighborhood of zero must contains the non empty interval of $\Bbb R$ and so has a limit point in $G$ and all points in $U$, $g$ vanishes, so by identity theorem $f$ is identically equals $k$